# How to prove: ${X_n}$ Uniform absolute continuous and $X_n$ Convergence in probability to $X$ equivalent to $X$ in $L_p$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, lp-spaces

Help me my friends! Our teacher left a remark on the notes without providing a proof, which I am very curious about. It says that

> If $\{|X_n|^p,n\geq1\}$ is uniform absolute continuous, and $X_n\xrightarrow{P}X$, then $$X\in L_p$$

---

The definition of **Uniform Absolute Continuous** is provided as

> Uniform absolute continuous: For all $\varepsilon$, there exists $\eta_{\varepsilon}$, such that for any $A \in \mathcal{A}$, if $\mathbb{P}(A)<\eta_{\varepsilon}$, then
> $$
> \sup\limits_{i\in I}\mathbb{E}\left(|X_i|\mathbf{1}_A\right)<\varepsilon.
> $$

I know that **with uniformly bounded moments**, we can obtain **uniform integrability** from uniform absolute continuity, and hence I can easily prove that the r.v sequence is Lp convergent. However in this case, I **do not have uniformly bounded moments**.

From Fatou-Lebesgue Lemma, I can show that
$$
\mathbb{E}|X|^p=\mathbb{E}\left[\liminf_{k\to\infty}|X_{n_k}|^p\right]\leq\liminf_{k\to\infty}\mathbb{E}|X_n|^p\leq\sup_n\mathbb{E}|X_n|^p.
$$

But sadly this is how far I can get. How am I gonna prove that $\mathbb{E}|X_n|^p$ are all finite? Any helpful comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some issues if the r.v takes the value of infinity with a positive probability. So the proof shown above is actually a little bit erroneous. Sorry I've been busy on my school work recently and didn't come back. If anyone wants a rigorous proof of the question, please refer to the following website, where I have posted a proof [labeld as Remark 2 in the file] written by my teacher.
[enter link description here](https://blueshot.lanzoum.com/i2RbX1hzwtte)

Comment: Link only posts are discouraged. Please consider writing the proof down using MathJax.

Comment: You should post that proof here in MathJax, posting link as answer may be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

By going to a subsequence we may suppose $X_n \to X$ a.s.
By Fatou's Lemma $E|X|^{p}1_{|X|>M} \leq \lim \inf_n E|X_n|^{p}1_{|X|>M}$. Choose $M$ such that $P(|X|>M)<\eta_{\epsilon}$ and apply the hypothesis to see that $E|X|^{p}1_{|X|>M}\leq \epsilon$. Of course, $E|X|^{p}1_{|X|\leq M}\leq M^{p}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! As I mentioned above, I was wondering if I can indeed find such M without the assumption of uniformly bounded moment? If the momoent, i.e., $E|X_n|$does not exists, can I really find such M?

Comment: You only need $M$ such that $P(|X|>M)<\eta_{\epsilon}$, Such an $M$ exists simply because $(|X|>M)$ decreases to empty set as $M$ increases to $\infty$ @DalaBomba

Comment: Okay, seems reasonable to me. Thank you again for your comment!

Comment: Do you need further assitance?  I will be glad to help. Withdrawal of the approval when  there is no other solution sounds very misterious.